# Import page component alternative vue.js

Tags: php, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using a plain PHP site with vue.js and want to import components, As I see import only works for node and vue? 
Is there a solution?
I'm really not that good.

import and require js pages

```js
import settings from 'settings.html';
Vue.component('app-settings', settings);
import Form from 'settings.js';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I'm sorry for the short description, it really frustrated me because all the tutorials are form the npm vue version.
I created a file named settings.js in the assets/js folder.
This is also the place for my app.js file where I wanted to include all the components like in the snippet I pasted in here.

Answer (score 2):

VueJS built on the top of ES6, so vuejs require babel in order to work.
Note: I really do not know why you want to use vuejs and plain PHP, 
you should make a PHP API, API that provides data for front-end,
you cannot use PHP and VueJS in one file because of vuejs code must pass on babel.
you should make a PHP API (RESTful API or Graphql), and you will fetch data from API to the front by using axios, fetch or Apollo or whatever.